# Scale Image in Landscape

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have a set of comic pages loaded in a recycler view, on rotation to landscape i would the image does not fill out the screen and if i set the scale type to fitxy the image is stretched and the aspect ratio is off. How can I have the image  fit landscape similarly to other comic or manga readers.

Here is my image view

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/page_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is where i load images in recyclerview

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(storageRef.child(mChapters.getComicTitle() + "/Chapter " +
                        mChapters.getChapterNumber() + "/" + currentPage.getPageImage()))
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        ((ComicReaderHolder) holder).loadingPageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        ((ComicReaderHolder) holder).loadingPageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(((ComicReaderHolder) holder).pageImage);
```

Comment: Assuming you are using the main.xml file ==> create the / res / layout-land file ==> copy main.xml to the layout-land directory ==>  custom your view when rotation to landscape

Comment: i will try this when i get a chance, does this automatically make the image adjust without losing stretching ? as said i want the image  to fit the screen but not stretch @Pain